# Value [string] <br> [string] <br> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: php, android, sql

I am making an app wherein I fetch user data from the corresponding sql table using php.

```
<?php 

$email = $_POST["email"];

@mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die(@mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db("dtbse") or die(@mysql_error());

$x = mysql_query("select * from dtbse where email = '$email' ") or die(@mysql_error());
$result = array();

while ($y=mysql_fetch_array($x)) {
            echo $y["uname"]."<br>";
            echo $y["gender"]."<br>";
            echo $y["pass"]."<br>";
            echo $y["address"]."<br>";
            echo $y["email"]."<br>";

        }

?>
```

Any help will be greatly apprecitated.  I know this question has been a lot of times but I dont think there is something replicating this issue. Thanks.

Here is the code snippet responsible for fetching and parsing.
    final ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        arr.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", uname));

```
            try {

                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxyoxx.esy.es/getDetails.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(arr));
                HttpResponse hr = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity ent = hr.getEntity();
                is = ent.getContent();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"1 wrk ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            } catch (Exception fl) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"First Try error "+fl,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            /*// Depends on your web service
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");*/

            String result=null;
            try {
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"2 str\n "+result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception sl) {
                sl.printStackTrace();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"2 err\n "+sl,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            try{
                String aa = "", b = "", c = "";
                JSONArray ar = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < ar.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jo = ar.getJSONObject(i);
                    aa = jo.getString("uname");
                    b = jo.getString("address");
                    c = jo.getString("email");
                }
                nm.setText(aa);
                addr.setText(b);
                mail.setText(c);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"3 wrk"+result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch (Exception tl){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"3 err "+tl,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Comment: please post your json data

Comment: Do not use the error suppression operator. Never ever. There is absolutely no valid use case for it.

Comment: It's an error on your JSON response, It's report the tipical orange square error then you receive <br>.... show your URL on comercial browser to see better your response.

Comment: @DaminiMehra Don't know how to that. Noob here.

Comment: @apokryfos Duly noted. You mean the
    `die(@mysql_error())`
right?

Comment: I mean any function which is prefixed with `@` which seems to be most of them

Comment: @apokryfos I see what you mean but I am familiar with this, and this has served me well so no issues. Any insights on the string not getting parsed issue? Is it the <br>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings separated by `<br>` are not a valid JSON array. PHP can create JSON strings using `json_encode`

If you need to read a JSON array in Android you need to echo a JSON array from PHP:

```
<?php 

$email = $_POST["email"];

mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dtbse") or die(mysql_error());

$x = mysql_query("select * from dtbse where email = '$email' ") or die(mysql_error());
$result = array();

$res=[];    
while ($y=mysql_fetch_array($x)) {
     $res[] = [ 
              $y["uname"], 
              $y["gender"],                   
              $y["pass"], 
              $y["address"],
              $y["email"] 
     ];    
 }
 echo json_encode($res); //Make PHP return a valid JSON response
```

Also, the error suppression operators may hide valuable debug infomation which may help you diagnose other problems.

If you instead prefer to pass the JSON object to Java then you can do the following (simpler) thing.

```
<?php 

$email = $_POST["email"];

mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dtbse") or die(mysql_error());

$x = mysql_query("select * from dtbse where email = '$email' ") or die(mysql_error());
$result = array();

$res=[];    
while ($y=mysql_fetch_array($x)) {
     $res[] = $y;
 }
 echo json_encode($res); //Make PHP return a valid JSON response
```

Comment: Yes this solved the problem. But now I am plagued with a new one. Value ["string","string"] at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be coverted to JSONObject.

Comment: @cenobia if your android app is expecting a JSON object for each "row" then you probably need to modify your PHP accordingly.  I've made an update in case it's helpful